# Do I need a tune up or a transmission

Tags: engine-theory

My 2001 Buick LaSabre with 106000 miles started hesitating changing gears and roughly doing so.  I stopped and shopped for about an hour and started driving again, and it changed gears smoothly with no more trouble. It's due for a tune up. Could a tune up be the problem or it have to be the transmission is failing.

Comment: A tune-up is not going to help with transmission problems.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a tranny fluid flush? This helps with reducing shift harshness in general and might(hopefully in your case) be the cause of the shift hesitation!